# custom dictionaries in quanteda

Tags: text, encoding, quanteda

I need to do LIWC(Linguistic Inquiry and Word Count)and I am using quanteda/quanteda.dictionaries. I need to "load" custom dictionaries: i saved my word lists  as individual .txt files and a "load" the through readlines (example with just one dictionary):

```
autonomy = readLines("Dictionary/autonomy.txt", encoding = "UTF-8")

EODic<-quanteda::dictionary(list(autonomy=autonomy),encoding = "auto")
```

This is a text that I am trying it on

```
txt <- c("12th Battalion Productions is producing a fully holographic feature length production. Presenting a 3D audio-visual projection without a single cast member present, to give the illusion of live stage performance.")
```

Then I run it:

```
liwcalike(txt, EODic, what = "word")
```

and get this error:

```
Error in stri_replace_all_charclass(value, "\\p{Z}", concatenator) : 


invalid UTF-8 byte sequence detected; perhaps you should try calling stri_enc_toutf8()
```

Obviously, the problem is with my txt file. I have quite a few dictionaries and rather load them as files.

How can I fix this error? specifying encoding in readlines does not seem to help

Here is the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/12plgfJdMawmqTkcLWxD1BfWdaeHuPTXV/view?usp=sharing

Update: the easiest way to solve this on Mac was to open the .txt file in Word rather than TextEdit. Word gives options for encoding unlike default TextEdit!

Comment: Without a reproducible example of your file, it’s impossible to know the source of the error. But it sounds like your input word list is not encoded as UTF-8. The “encoding” argument in `readlines()` will not re-encode the file, it only tells R to treat the text as if it were UTF-8. My suggestion is to open the file in a text editor and save it explicitly as UTF-8. Or, provide a link to the file to make the problem reproducible.

Comment: thanks Ken, added a link there, I am on Mac, when I open in TextEdit and save it, it does not give me the option with encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the problem is not an encoding one, since everything in the file you linked could be encoded entirely in the lower-128 character ASCII.  The problem was the blanks caused by empty lines.  There are also leading spaces that need removal.  This is easy to do using some subsetting and some **stringi** cleanup operations.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 1.3.14

autonomy <- readLines("~/Downloads/risktaking.txt", encoding = "UTF-8")
head(autonomy, 15)
##  [1] "adventuresome"  " adventurous"   " audacious"     " bet"          
##  [5] " bold"          " bold-spirited" " brash"         " brave"        
##  [9] " chance"        " chancy"        " courageous"    " danger"       
## [13] ""               "dangerous"      " dare"

# strip leading or trailing whitespace
autonomy <- stringi::stri_trim_both(autonomy)
# get rid of empties
autonomy <- autonomy[!autonomy == ""]
```

Now you can create the dictionary and apply the `quanteda.dictionaries::liwcalike()` function.

```r
# now define the quanteda dictionary
EODic <- dictionary(list(autonomy = autonomy))

txt <- c("12th Battalion Productions is producing a fully holographic feature length production. Presenting a 3D audio-visual projection without a single cast member present, to give the illusion of live stage performance.")

library("quanteda.dictionaries")
liwcalike(txt, dictionary = EODic)
##   docname Segment WC  WPS Sixltr Dic autonomy AllPunc Period Comma Colon
## 1   text1       1 35 15.5  34.29   0        0   11.43   5.71  2.86     0
##   SemiC QMark Exclam Dash Quote Apostro Parenth OtherP
## 1     0     0      0 2.86     0       0       0   8.57
```

Comment: Ken, thank you. i did work and interestingly, saving in word made it work as well.